# YouTube v.3: Getting uploads playlist ID for user without human-friendly username

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

OK so no programming as such, but this is driving me mad, so I'm putting my faith in SO.

Using YouTube API v.3, I can easily get the ID of the uploads playlist associated with a particular user, like this:

```
{BASE_URL}/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=some_user&key=my_key
```

However, for all that I read and try, I cannot figure out how to do this for users with more obscure, ID-esque IDs, e.g.

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_tt4cYHIHNQAFQj2V2Wi-w
```

Trying:

```
{BASE_URL}/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=UC_tt4cYHIHNQAFQj2V2Wi-w&key=my_key
```

...yields a JSON response with no results, implying I can't use that long `UC_...` string as a username.

Does anyone know a way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the id param for when you have the UC type id

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I actually love you. Thanks a bunch.